# Incorrect tests but not sure what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python

The code I am creating is basically you are given a number and a base. You divide the number by the base and receive a quotient and remainder. You continue doing this until the quotient value is zero and then you add up the remainders as a string and return that.

Remainder values of 10+ start becoming letters.

I had submitted this code to GitHub to grade by my professor but I am getting errors of incorrect tests? I am pretty sure the tests work out but I am not sure why I'm getting a zero on them.

```
def convert(num: int, base: int) -> str:

    if num < base:
        return str(num) + ""
    remainder = (num % base)
    if remainder <= 9:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + str(remainder) + ""
    elif remainder == 10:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "A" + ""
    elif remainder == 11:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "B" + ""
    elif remainder == 12:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "C" + ""
    elif remainder == 13:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "D" + ""
    elif remainder == 14:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "E" + ""
    elif remainder == 15:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "F" + ""
    elif remainder == 16:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "G" + ""
    elif remainder == 17:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "H" + ""
    elif remainder == 18:
        return str(convert(num // base, base)) + "I" + ""
```

```
import unittest

from base_convert import convert

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_convert_base02_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(107, 2), '1101011')

    def test_convert_base10_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(107, 10), '107')

    def test_convert_base10_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(500, 10), '500')

    def test_convert_base04_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(30, 4), '132')

    def test_convert_base15_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(164, 14), '11A')

    def test_convert_base16_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(107, 16), '6B')

    def test_covert_base16_c(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(316, 16), '13C')

    def test_convert_base17_d(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(513, 17), '1D3')

    def test_convert_base15_e(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(164, 15), '10E')

    def test_convert_base16_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(175, 16), '10F')

    def test_convert_base19_g(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(187, 19), '9G')

    def test_convert_base21_h(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(164, 21), '7H')

    def test_convert_base19_i(self):
        self.assertEqual(convert(208, 19), '10I')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Your issue occurs when `num < base` but `num` is greater than `9`

Comment: Not really your question, but `strings.ascii_uppercase` contains 'ABCDEFG...Z'.  You could use this instead of your seven different cases of adding a letter.  You also can also delete the `+ ""`.  It doesn't do anything.